# Apache - Restrict to IP not working

Tags: apache-2.2

I've a subdomain that I only want to be accessible internally; I'm trying to achieve this in Apache by editing the VirtualHost block for that domain. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? Note, my internal IP address here are 192.168.10.xxx. My code is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.epiphanydev2.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_test_co_uk.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_test_co_uk.log combined
  <Directory /var/www/test>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.10.0/24
    Allow from 127
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
<Directory /var/www/test>
  Order  deny, allow
  deny from all
  Allow from 192.168.10.0/24
  Allow from 127
</Directory>
```

Reload apache.